# How to view big files on Windows?

Tags: text-editors, viewer

Sometimes we need to view large files - 30M-100M.

Usually we use FAR viewer for this.  Sometimes we need to copy to clipboard long traces from this file.  But it is possible to copy only one screen in FAR viewer.

What can be used for this purpose?
It should be GUI and freeware.

**UPDATE:**
We need to have ability navigate over the file and see updates of the file in the meantime (eg `tail -f`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My two cents:

- [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) - a text editor I have been using for a while, opens large files with relative ease
- [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) - a great tail program with highlighting and multiple tabs

Comment: baretail is good!

Answer (score 1):

You can open very large files in a standard web browser without issues.

Comment: I need to see updates of the file without refreshing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) should have no problems opening files of that size.

Comment: Does it have "tail -f" feature?

Comment: notepad++ is horrible on large files. Compare it to opening the same file in Textpad. If you want tail -f functionality try http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Comment: We need both - to have ability navigate over the file and see updates of the file in the meantime(tail -f )

Answer (score 0):

You can install Cygwin and use all the usual Linux tools, including 'tail -f'.

Comment: FAR have this feature not only linux tools.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [WinTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/wintail) - it'll perform all the Tail functionality that you need, as well as handle large files.

[image: Wintail]

Comment: >>WinTail allows you to view the last 64K of a growing text file in real time under Win32 operating systems.

But we need to see all file not only last 64K.

Answer (score 0):

I use the text editor Vim, which runs under lots of operating systems and (in my experience, anyway) deals very well with large files. You can pick it up here:

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

Any text editor, though, is going to choke a bit on a file of that size. Is there any way you can filter the file down to the size you need? If there is a string all the traces you need contain, you are probably best served by reducing the file to lines containing that string, which is a quick operation:

```
c:\> find "2009/04/07" tracefile.txt > 20090407.txt
```

Comment: There is no "tail -f" feature in Vim.

Comment: But vim recognizes a change of the file opened and asks you if you want to do a reload.

Comment: File will be updated very frequently.
And I do not want to answer on the questions of the vim.

Answer (score 0):

Not a GUI tool, but you can use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), too. Here's a link that will help:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30168576/any-command-like-the-tail.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**[Tail4Win](http://www.withdata.com/tail4win.html)** might be exactly what you're looking for but it ain't free.